# How to record video with webcam in Safari on iOS and macOS?

Tags: video, safari, webrtc, webcam

I've released several paths:

1) Recording video with https://caniuse.com/#feat=html-media-capture
But it works only on iOS and cannot be customizable. I need to render a red frame over the video preview layer and limit video length to 30 seconds.

2) Recording with a WebRTC client placed on the server, but I can't find any software to do that. I've found kurento media server, but its client js utils library does not support Safari 11.

3) Recording with flash plugin. But it is not supported on iOS.

Can you help me to find some other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The MediaStream Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API) would be a good option but it's not implemented in Safari yet. There is an [open ticket](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85851) for this that you should comment on.

Another option while waiting for that is to use the Archiving API in TokBox/OpenTok. You can see a sample of it working [here](https://opentok.github.io/opentok-web-samples/Archiving/) and documentation [here](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/). It works in Safari 11 if you [opt into a Safari project](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/safari/). It will let you archive a video and store it in the cloud, eg. S3. You will then need to download it. There are also costs associated with this, you will need to [sign up for a TokBox account](https://tokbox.com/account/user/signup).

(disclosure I work at TokBox )

Answer (score 0):

MediaRecorder API is also another option but " Safari is currently not supporting MediaRecorder API by default, but you can enable them from **Develop > Experimental Features > MediaRecorder**"

Comment: yeah tell your customers that :D