# How to save video stream recorded from webcam in safari browser?

Tags: safari, webrtc, webcam

`Safari` doesn't support `MediaRecorder` to listen to the stream from WebCam like the below code.
This works perfectly in `Chrome` and I'm able to convert the blob to a webm video file.

```
 if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia)
        {
               
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}).then (stream => {

                videoRef.srcObject = stream 

                mediaRecorder.value = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp8,opus'})
                
                mediaRecorder.value.addEventListener('dataavailable', function(e) { 

                          blobs.push(e.data)

                  })

                }) 
        }

 })
```

I need to save the video streamed from webcam in my server. What should be the approach to achieve the same in `Safari`?

I researched a lot, saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003715/how-to-record-video-with-webcam-in-safari-on-ios-and-macos). But there was no proper solution given.

Could someone guide to a tutorial on how to achieve this using WebRTC if needed?

Comment: the latestSafari should actually support it: https://webkit.org/blog/11353/mediarecorder-api/

Comment: That's good news, I guess i'll just wait for the update to roll out